# Why isn’t stackexchange.com using the same mobile layout as other SE sites in my browser?

Tags: bug, mobile-web, stackexchange.com

I can see most SE sites and pages mobile friendly, including this one. But for just stackexchange.com it displays full desktop on mobile chrome and safari. Is there something I need to change on my end? See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Stackexchange.com never got the mobile love, nor responsive love it needs. I believe it was once decided that it needed an overhaul but I've not seen it being mentioned in the roadmaps so far so I guess this work got pushed back by 6 to 8 weeks ...